# How to Save Terminal Text from Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: terminal, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I'd like to save the entire terminal text after running a series of commands in Google Cloud Shell similar to the *Export Text As...* option on MacOS Terminal.

Is the [script command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) my answer or is there a `gcloud` thing I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works) runs a debian based OS therefor  [script command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) will work.

Once you have the file if you want to download you can get the full path with `pwd` and then download option on the the points options menu

Comment: I went with `script` which works well but with a caveat that's mentioned on its man page: _all_ output is stored including any control characters like backspace/formfeed. I'd really like something which keeps only the final output because the interim progress bars and so forth really bloat the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try put " > name.txt " at the end of command to get what you wanted in directory:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK